# ZedGraph in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, zedgraph

I hope someone can help me.

I'm trying to make a text box on a graph with information for the user.

I have:

```
GraphPane^ myPaneTemp = zedGraphTeP->GraphPane;
TextObj text = gcnew TextObj(
                "Zoom: left mouse & drag\nPan: middle mouse & drag\nContext Menu: right mouse", 0.72f, 0.13f, CoordType::PaneFraction, AlignH::Left, AlignV::Bottom);
```

text.FontSpec->StringAlignment = StringAlignment::Near;

Now I want to add to graph:

```
myPaneTemp->GraphObjList->Add(text);
```

But I got an error message:

> error C2664: 'System::Collections::Generic::List::Add' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ZedGraph::TextObj' to 'ZedGraph::GraphObj ^'

how can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be TextObj^ text ?

Comment: Not. It does not solve the problem.

Comment: And you're sure it still the same problem? After modifying that line, did you also change text.FontSpec to text->FontSpec  ?

Comment: You're right  
Is   
TextObj ^text = gcnew TextObj(
                "Zoom: left mouse & drag\nPan: middle mouse & drag\nContext Menu: right mouse", 0.72f, 0.13f, CoordType::PaneFraction, AlignH::Left, AlignV::Bottom);

And

text->FontSpec...

Thanks

Comment: @Michael Great comments! Since your comments contain the solution to the problem, maybe you could write a real answer to the question, to make it easier for other readers to find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing my comments into an answer for future reference:

`gcnew TextObj` gives you a handle, so you need to change `TextObj text` to `TextObj^ text` and `text.FontSpec` to `text->FontSpec`